# Rename a directory containing many files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, command-line-interface, shell

I made a mistake in a `rsync` and all the files are copied long with its full path. All the files that I copied are at

```
/var/www/photos/2012/1007/1007
```

**Attempt 1**

Now I would like to fix the paths, by doing

```
 mv /var/www/photos/2012/1007/1007 /var/www/photos/2012
```

This gives the error:

```
mv: cannot move `/var/www/photos/2012/1007/1007' to `/var/www/photos/2012/1007': Directory not empty
```

**Attempt 2**

```
 mv /var/www/photos/2012/1007/1007/* /var/www/photos/2012/1007
```

I get the error:

```
-bash: /bin/mv: Argument list too long
```

**Question:** What will be the correct way to rename the folder that contains alot of files?

---

*The files were actually copied to `/var/www/photos/2012/1007/home/photos/public_html/2012/1007` but somehow I got them to `/var/www/photos/2012/1007/1007`*

*Rsync cmd:*

*`rsync -zavrR --rsh="ssh -c arcfour -l root -p 2200" www.mydomain.com:/home/photos/public_html/2012/1007 /var/www/photos/2012/1007`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked in my test with the paths you gave:

```
cd /var/www/photos
mv 2012 old
mv old/1007/1007 .
mv 1007 2012
```

What's happening is you are trying to move a directory over top of an existing directory - and it doesn't like doing that because there's stuff in the directory.  By renaming 2012 first, you can move it without problems.

Comment: Awesome!!!! Will need to `mv old 2012` before `mv 1007 2012`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At least two ways I can think of:

**1:** First rename /var/www/photos/2012/1007 to /var/www/photos/2012/temppath, then mv /var/www/photos/2012/temppath/1007 -> /var/www/photos/2012/, then rmdir /var/www/photos/2012/temppath.

**2:** Use a simple script to move the contents:

```
for f in `find /var/www/photos/2012/1007/1007 -mindepth 1`; do mv $f /var/www/photos/2012/1007/1007/../; done
```

First method it probably a better answer to your question.

Comment: Too late I was...